# Getting Same Message Again And Again From FB-Messanger Webhook

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger-bot

Making a bot for messenger platform in php. Everything is working fine. But after a certain amount of time the I start receiving same message again and again on fb webhook.[image: Image requests from fb]

Note: Everything is same in request except the time. And then fb blocks my account due to unusual activity.

Any help ?

Comment: Genius I received that response when laravel development server is not running i.e. localhost:8000 is not running. I was receiving those messages way before this. Back then it was 200 ok. How would you explain that ?

Comment: What request are you sending that is returning that webhook event?

Comment: okay I am not sending any "requests". Let me explain this to you, Whenever a fb user reaches my fb page (book store page) and if he/she sends a message that webhook is called.. this phenomena is called fb chatting. Now, either a human can reply or the like in my case I have set up a bot for this. So, in short whenever someone sends me a message it comes on this webhook. But my problem is the sender is sending one message but I am receiving it more then 100 times. Now you got the problem Sir ?

Comment: Yes, I understand how messenger works, but misunderstood the problem you were having. When you first receive the event, do you respond with a 200 OK? If you don't do this, messenger platform will continue to retry sending the event

Comment: okay may be i didn't explained it good enough earlier.
yes i did respond with 200 ok. But in one case I reply back with a carousel, in that caseits taking more then 20 s to respond.

Comment: Are you sending the 200 response separately? You can't respond to the event with a message. You have to respond with 200, then send the message separately.

Comment: check my answer please as I found the issue and yes you are right. :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152516/discussion-between-junaid-ahmad-and-amuramoto).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem as I also talked to fb support. 
First, we were using queues for replying back to user. In that case the response 200 ok was going back immediately but since we removed queues I think this is causing the error. But again, the issue that fb is sending me 100 of messages (as I talked to them and they said that we checked our server's and yes we were sending messages as we thought they were failing, since reply was not going back within 20s) is intact at its place. I mean they should try it like 4 or 5 times maximum, if replying in not 200 ok, then they should stop sending the same message again and again.